# Mining Zcash using cluster of GPU's

Tags: hashpower, gpu, zcash

I have a basic knowledge about an idea of cryptocurriencies. Recently I have read articles about Zcash. Rumours has it that it's the most profitable cryptocurrency on the scene. Me and my co-worker want to mine Zcash. I know that we need high hashing power. I was thinking about cluster of high-end graphical cards. With our budget we can afford more or less 15 GPU's. My very basic calculation says that we should have something around 300.000 MH/s. Will it be profitable and feasible assuming we want perform solo mining? Is there a good piece of software for Zcash solo mining?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Profitability will all depend on the cards you buy, your electricity cost, and your overclocking configurations. I haven’t mined zcash in a few weeks, but when I was mining I was getting about $12ish dollars a day with 3 Nvidia 1070 Ti’s. My hash power was about 1560 sols/s(zcash’s version of a h/s). Each card was running at 85% power and getting around 520 sols/s.

I would say at 15 cards, and the hashing power you mentioned, you should be more than profitable. If you want to get a good idea of how much you will make, checkout whattomine.com, it’s a great resource for measuring profitability.

Answer (score 0):

Solo mining is not profitable. Use something pool for ZCash.
And now try to mining other altcoins for example Stipend or FOLM whatever, Altcoins gave you more profit, than ZCash. 100% percent. Altcoins you can find here howtomine.online it is not spam if you want delete the link.